# Form to enter City and Country in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, geonames

My application has a form where you need to enter a purchase in (date, amount, description, location etc). 
The location part is where im struggling a little. I'm trying to decide on the easiest method to enter City and Country so that later i can sort the data via, city or country.

At the moment it is two text fields for each.

I've seen this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460269/need-a-list-of-cities-countries) and it is the closest thing i've seen to being useful.

My question is then, what is the most user friendly way to enter location data for purchases in rails? Should i just leave them as text fields and compare it with a database of names like mentioned in that link?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

For cities picker you can use https://github.com/joecorcoran/cities at least (and use classic country/city combos). No need to pollute database with this. If you want to be fancy - you can use google maps to pick location.

Comment: so use a pulldown with all countries, and then once selected fill a drop down with all cities? This gem fast enough for it you reckon, ill give it a go tonight. I'll probably end up going the google maps route, but for now i just need something simple.

Comment: btw - this gem got pretty extensive list of cities (you may want to  filter them by population or find another one with smaller lists - there are plenty).

Comment: you can also "guess" country and city with geop lib. country list is free while city one are quite expensive.

Answer (score 0):

The [Google Places Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#places_autocomplete) offers a fantastic user experience for selecting a location, at the cost of a bit of JS work to make sure you store the data you need (and of relying on a 3rd party API).

Answer (score -1):

https://github.com/sgruhier/jquery-addresspicker.git

Check this Out .It will solve your problem.

Comment: ahh that's awesome! I'm gonna give this a go. Cheers.